# Using Attributes to Call Methods

Tags: c#, reflection, architecture, attributes, aop

I have various individual methods which all need to perform the same functions before continuing on with their own implementation. Now I could implement these functions in each method, but I was wondering if there's a way to exploit `attributes` to do this? As a very simple example, all network calls have to check for a network connection.

```
public void GetPage(string url)
{
   if(IsNetworkConnected())
      ...
   else
      ...           
}
```

This would work, but I'd have to call the `IsNetworkConnected` method for each method that uses the network and handle it individually. Instead, I'd like to do this

```
[NetworkCall]
public void GetPage(string url)
{
   ...
}
```

If the network is unavailable, an error method is called instead and `GetPage` is ignored, otherwise `GetPage` is invoked.

This sounds very much like Aspect Orientated Programming, but I don't want to implement an entire framework for a few calls. This is more of a learning exercise than an implementation one, so I was curious as to how something like this would be best implemented.

Comment: What about inheritance? Make all of them derive from a base "Network" class or something like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), it is aspect-oriented framework for .NET, it seems [quite easy to use](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo();
}

[IgnoreMethod(IsIgnored=true)]
public static void Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing Foo()...");
}

[Serializable]
public class IgnoreMethodAttribute : PostSharp.Aspects.MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public bool IsIgnored { get; set; }

    public override void OnInvoke(PostSharp.Aspects.MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (IsIgnored)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnInvoke(args);
    }
}
```

**Method-Level Aspects** feature is available in the **free** edition: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/purchase/compare

Run-Time Performance:

> Because PostSharp is a compiler technology, most of the expensive work is done at build time, so that applications start quickly and execute fast. When generating code, PostSharp takes the assumption that calling a virtual method or getting a static field is an expensive operation. Contrary to rumor, PostSharp does not use System.Reflection at run time.
>   http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/performance

Comment: I thought PostSharp would be inefficient because it has to go through a layer of reflection...but it *sounds* like it does most of it's stuff at compile-time. Nice, clean API. I might give this a try for some of my projects.

Comment: Yes, have just read on their website: `"Contrary to rumor, PostSharp does not use System.Reflection at run time."`
http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/performance
So, the performance doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into PostSharp. I didn't particularly want to use a framework, but doesn't seem there's an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with `attributes` only, because they are not executed by the runtime if you're not actively doing something with them. A lightweight approach would be [Ninject with Interceptions extension](http://codepyre.com/2010/03/using-ninject-extensions-interception-part-1-the-basics/), it is a framework, but a very thin one, and one you might already be using for DI anyway.

Another option, but a bit more involved, could be based on [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx), and then you can use attributes and do something during with them during activation.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it sounds a lot like AOP.
What you're after sounds like compile time weaving? I.e. the attribute is turned into additional code by the compiler.
You could look at how to implement this...
[Generating additional code through a custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066218/generating-additional-code-through-a-custom-attribute)
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~eaddy/wicca/ &
http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net/compiletime-weaving
all refer to tools and techniques for doing this.

Or you could use an AOP framework. IMHO, you should look at AOP frameworks.